# Read-only routing feature in SQL Server 2016 Availability Groups

Tags: sql-server

I don't know much about the feature, my question is as now we can send read-only workload to secondary replica .

My question is what will perform better

single instance with 32 cpu

1 primary and 1 secondary  with 16 cpu each or

1 primary and 2 secondaries 12 cpu each

Or in other way is the number of worker threads affected by the number of cpu in the primary only or the number of cpu of all members in Availability Groups

Comment: SO what is your question .. I am still unclear ! See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alwaysonpro/2016/05/02/sql-server-2016-alwayson-availability-group-enhancements-load-balance-read-only-routing/

Answer (score 0):

A readable secondary is a completely separate SQL instance on its own server. It has its own resources, worker threads, etc. It does not use anything on the primary server. With read-only routing in place, SQL Server will redirect the read-intent queries to the readable secondary. It doesn't partially run that query on the primary.